# the type reference cannot find public type named

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, .net-4.6.1

I'm getting an error about 'the type reference cannot find public type named ...' I have the error in 2 xaml files. 1 with ComboboxiTem. and another one in datagridColumnHeader.
As for the comboboxitem -> the items are from a list and gets loaded on the 'onLoaded' event trigger. For some reason the code works perfectly but when i try to edit or even open the file and let it generate again it give me this error.

No matter where I search or what I do it just does not seem to fix this problem :(. When i overwrite the file it does work again and can generate. but yet again even when opening it i'm doomed. 
Does anyone know how to fix this issue and or why i'm getting this error.

ps: As a side note. this is NOT created in visual studio but created in a custom IDE build in a cms system with it's own intellisense and compiler written in .net 4.6.1 and uses windows controls and or telerik controls

'''
Datagridcolumnheader error

```
<!--saved by ADM on BEPP15366 with appConfig.exe v4.5.2.0 on 27/06/2019 08:15:18-->
<app:Synoptic x:Class="appClient_gen.Psim_ResponsiblesEditor"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:app="http://prysm.fr/AppVision"
xmlns:video="http://prysm.fr/AppVideo"
xmlns:gen="clr-namespace:appClient_gen" InitialWidth="1280" InitialHeight="900" Format="2.0" AppVersion="4.5.2.0" Date="2019-06-27 08:15:18Z">
  <app:SynoItem.AnimationItems>
    <app:ActionAnim x:Key="script">
      <app:CData xml:space="preserve"><![CDATA[private System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Responsible> responsibles;
private System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Parameter> parameters;

public override void OnLoaded() 
{ 
responsibles = Responsible.GetResponsibles();
dataGrid.ItemsSource = responsibles;
dataGrid.Columns[0].Width=(new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLength(0.05, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLengthUnitType.Star));
dataGrid.Columns[1].Width=(new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLength(0.35, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLengthUnitType.Star));
dataGrid.Columns[2].Width=(new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLength(0.35, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLengthUnitType.Star));
dataGrid.Columns[3].Width=(new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLength(0.25, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLengthUnitType.Star));
dataGrid.CanUserDeleteRows = false;
dataGrid.CanUserAddRows = false;
//dataGrid.Controls[0].BackColor = Color.Gray;
parameters = Parameter.GetParameters();
dataGrid2.ItemsSource = parameters;
dataGrid2.Columns[0].Width=(new System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLength(1.0, System.Windows.Controls.DataGridLengthUnitType.Star));
dataGrid2.CanUserDeleteRows = false;
dataGrid2.CanUserAddRows = false;
//dataGrid2.Controls[0].BackColor = Color.Gray;
}
public override void OnUnloaded() { }
public override void OnVariableStateChanged(VariableState state) { }
public override void OnAlarmChanged(AlarmInfo alarm) { }
public override void OnIdle() { }
protected override void OnMouseDoubleClick(MouseButtonEventArgs e) { base.OnMouseDoubleClick(e); }
]]></app:CData>
    </app:ActionAnim>
  </app:SynoItem.AnimationItems>
  <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Width="912" Height="793" Margin="68,258,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="-36" Canvas.Top="-184">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
      <Style TargetType="System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="System.Windows.Documents.TextElement.Foreground">
          <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush>#FF000000</SolidColorBrush>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
      <BindingGroup x:Name="{x:Null}" NotifyOnValidationError="False" ValidatesOnNotifyDataError="True" SharesProposedValues="True" />
    </DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="System.Windows.Documents.TextElement.Foreground">
          <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush>#FF000000</SolidColorBrush>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
  </DataGrid>
  <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid2" Width="282" Height="717" Margin="68,258,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="896" Canvas.Top="-184">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
      <Style TargetType="System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="System.Windows.Documents.TextElement.Foreground">
          <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush>#FF000000</SolidColorBrush>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
      <BindingGroup x:Name="{x:Null}" NotifyOnValidationError="False" ValidatesOnNotifyDataError="True" SharesProposedValues="True" />
    </DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="System.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow">
        <Setter Property="System.Windows.Documents.TextElement.Foreground">
          <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush>#FF000000</SolidColorBrush>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
  </DataGrid>
  <app:ButtonItem Text="Commit changes" Fill="#FF808080" Foreground="#FF000000" FontSize="24" x:Name="ButtonItem1" Width="280" Height="60" ToolTip="click to commit and activate changes" Canvas.Left="962" Canvas.Top="804">
    <app:SynoItem.AnimationItems>
      <app:ActionAnim x:Key="MouseLeftButtonUp">
        <app:CData xml:space="preserve"><![CDATA[ResponsiblesEditor.commitChangesClick(responsibles,parameters);
]]></app:CData>
      </app:ActionAnim>
    </app:SynoItem.AnimationItems>
  </app:ButtonItem>
  <app:RectangleItem Text="WorkFlow responsibles editor" Fill="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Foreground="#FF938953" FontSize="36" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Normal" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" x:Name="RectangleItem1" Width="1232" Height="52" Canvas.Left="23" Canvas.Top="16"></app:RectangleItem>
  <app:RectangleItem CornerRadius="10" Fill="#FFDDD9C2" Foreground="#FF000000" x:Name="RectangleItem2" Width="1256" Height="876" Canvas.ZIndex="-1" Canvas.Left="11" Canvas.Top="13"></app:RectangleItem>
</app:Synoptic>
```

the problem seems to be happening at this line : 
    Style TargetType="System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeader"

the same for comboboxitem also at targettype in style tag.

```
  <ComboBox x:Name="cBox" Width="149.8192" Height="22" 
Canvas.Left="23.7296000000033" Canvas.Top="40.7904000000016" 
Foreground="Black">
  <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
 </ComboBox>
```

Comment: What's up with the odd `Width`, `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` numbers?

Comment: thats the size of the windows. but I already found my solution apparently when the cms compiles the code it changes lines whereas my code would work. But I found a workaround.